I am trying to makee an H-bridge using MOSFETs. For some reason, my output is only going in the positive and not the negative
I am working on a FES stimulator.  I need an H-bridge connected so that I can apply bipolar currents to the muscle. While designing the H-bridge, I had no problem in Proteus but when trying it out in PSPICE I’m getting this error.
The output voltage reaches +100 V (muscle needs this much voltage for stimulation) but is only dropping to 0 V and not -100 V.
What can I do?
Schematic and resulting waveforms attached below:
This is the schematic:

This is the resulting wave form. The output is supposed to go below 0, but is not (the colour is of the voltage probe is the same in the graph.)


What functional safety requirements does the FES stimulator need to meet to ensure patient safety?

With respect to ground, your H-bridge can only produce positive voltages.
If you measure the voltage across your load R1, you will see bipolar voltages.
If you need bipolar voltage with regard to ground, you need a split power supply, at which point you can make do with a half-bridge unless you have specific freewheeling needs.

Your circuit has no -100V anywhere so it will not output -100V in any way.
However as each end of the load resistor alternates betweem 0V and 100V, the resistor does have either +100V and -100V over the terminals.
So the H-bridge works as expected (in the simulation), it can output 0V or 100V, and that's how it's drawn.
The circuit is also problematic, as the Vgs of the FET can only be +/- 20V before it damages. So even if it works in simulation, you would see fried chips in real life.
You are also using N-fets on the high side, and not driving the Vgs voltage but simply the gate, so they won't get fully turned on.

Thank you, i had to use 100V because the out put was limiting itself to the voltage given to the MOSFET, i will learn more about this :)
